# Bitbucket git push as user

Tags: git, bitbucket

1) I create a new repo on bitbucket using the main TEAM user.

2) Then i add all development keys that will be able to download this repo.

3) Went to a server and made a clone of this repo using the command:

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

4) I made some changes to the code and made the commit

```
git commit -a -m "some improves"
```

So here's the Question:

I can't do a git push bec i don't have push right to do that with this user:

```
# git push
conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So, how can i make a push using my username/password?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could always setup a second remote on your server using https:

```
git remote add edit-only-origin https://bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

Then, you could make small edits, commit and then use the command

```
git push edit-only-origin
```

This would prompt you for both your username and password.

Answer (score 21):

From my understanding, `deployment key` is for read-only access. To be able to push, you need to add your computer's `ssh` key.

Go to Manage Account, and on the left, choose SSH keys. Add key by copy and pasting your rsa.pub public key.

It's better if you copy it from terminal to make sure no funky characters get in the mix. To do so in OSX, type `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. For Linux, look at Agush's comment.

Comment: pbcopy is for OSX only, you should mention that.
For Linux there is ```xclip -sel c ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub```

Comment: If i do that anyone on the server is allowed to push changes to the master since it will not ask for a password.
I need a way to ask a password for push, but no limits to pull from master.

Comment: No, only the the user whose computer is registered with that SSH public key can push.

Comment: and how about https users?

Comment: Note that you will first have to delete the deployment key from **all** repos that currently use it; otherwise, you will get an error saying "Someone has already registered this as a deploy key.".

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you did use developer's key.
Need to add SSH-key in the profile and remove them in the repository-section.

Answer (score 5):

Try using HTTPS instead of SSH --

```
git -c user.email='myemail@gmail.com' -c user.name='myusername' commit
git push https://myusername@bitbucket.org/path-to/myrepos.git master
```

SSH uses the key, which in this case only gets you read access. HTTPS will prompt for your password, giving you write access to push.

Handy for quick edits on servers that are using read-only deployment keys.

Answer (score 0):

First bitbucket support ssh accesses.

I think you may add your key under a repo. The key in the repo is a deploy key and it doesn't have write permission.

If you want push permission, you should add the key under your account.

The link likes `https://bitbucket.org/account/user/#{the-org-name}/ssh-keys/`.